# Get column-property mapping relationship in MyBatis

Tags: mybatis

I need to do some dynamic sql mapping in the MyBatis, in order to let it do something like below for each column:

```
switch (filter.FilterType)
        {
            case FilterType.BeginsWith:
                operatorStr = "UPPER({0}) LIKE '{1}%' ";
                value = filter.Value.ToUpper();
                break;
            case FilterType.Contains:
                operatorStr = "UPPER({0}) LIKE '%{1}%' ";
                value = filter.Value.ToUpper();
                break;
            case FilterType.GreaterThan:
                operatorStr = " {0} > {1} ";
                break;
            case FilterType.GreaterThanOrEqual:
                operatorStr = " {0} >= {1} ";
                break;
            case FilterType.LessThan:
                operatorStr = " {0} < {1} ";
                break;
            case FilterType.LessThanOrEqual:
                operatorStr = " {0} <= {1} ";
                break;
        }
```

The reason I need to have a filter like this, is I have a web page where it shows a table's data as grid, and each column is searchable/sortable. I don't want to write if-else clause for each column, so trying to see if the column-property mapping in the Mybatis could help in this work.

I would like to have a way to let the Mybatis know which column I want it to point to be effective in the filter. I know I can use the simple dynamic way to achieve this by figure out dynamically in my own custom code of which actual column I want to filter. But I don't want to mix the actual table column names in the programming source code. The way I think it would be more sensible to do this is to pass a class property name into the Mybatis's API, then let it figure out which actual column that maps to the class's property name passed in.

Do anyone have ideas of how to do this? Is there an API in the Mybatis to provide this column-property mapping relationship function, eg. it could act like a dictionary, which I pass in the property name then it give me the actual column name?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Switch is not supported by mybatis so you can use  to achieve this

```
<choose>
            <when test=""></when>
            <when test=""></when>
            <when test=""></when>
            <when test=""></when>
            <otherwise></otherwise>
        </choose>
```

u can pass filter type as parameter and then verify it.